# layout_marginTop and layout_marginBottom does not work with nested RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I have a nested RelativeLayout. I want to add top margin and bottom margin. I specify as attributes:

```
android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
```

Here is more context:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
    style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputpassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:minHeight="36dp"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="OR"
    android:textColor="#000"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvText"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvText"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
/>

</RelativeLayout>

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:minHeight="119dp" android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```

But no margin is added. When I remove the two attributes, the layout_marginTop of the facebook button displays. But adding layout_marginBottom to the email_sign_in_button button does not create the margin either. Why doesn't the nested RelativeLayout display the margin?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's happening

The parent is a `RelativeLayout` (given the layout_* parameters).

**SIGN IN** button is at the top. *Directly below it* (layout_below) is **Login with Facebook** button. These two buttons make the whole bounding box.

In this bounding box is another `RelativeLayout` *centered vertically* so it's margins are ignored or produce unwanted results. There is no relation between this `RelativeLayout` and any of the buttons.

`RelativeLayout` is not a `LinearLayout` which is probably what you should be using.

## What to do with it

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button/>
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical"> <!-- Horizontal by default. -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
        <!-- DON'T use horizontal *margins* in horizontal LinearLayout! -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LoginButton/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can worry about optimizations later.

## Notes

- Add missing `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` attributes of course.
- When using `android:layout_weight` *always* specify the computed dimension as `0dp`.
- `android:layout_gravity` positions *this* view in its *parent*.
- `android:gravity` positions *children* of *this* view.